# Calcular porcentagem MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou querendo fazer um cálculo de porcentagem. Pegando o valor que foi recebido naquele mês selecionado (recebido = 1), dividir pelo valor total daquele mês selecionado, e multiplicar por 100 para retornar a porcentagem.
A lógica que utilizei abaixo está funcionando perfeitamente:

```
SET @total = (SELECT SUM(valor_receita) FROM receitas WHERE YEAR(data_vencimento) <= '2017' AND MONTH(data_vencimento) <= '06' AND id_usuario = 1);
SELECT SUM(valor_receita) AS valor_receita, ((SUM(valor_receita)/@total)*100) AS total
FROM receitas
WHERE recebido = 1 AND YEAR(data_vencimento) <= '2017' AND MONTH(data_vencimento) <= '06' AND id_usuario = 1;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu gostaria de saber é se tem alguma maneira de simplificar este query fazendo um JOIN ou algo do tipo... sem a necessidade de também repetir duas vezes o mês e ano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem alterar muito, você pode fazer com um subselect:

```
SELECT 
SUM(r.valor_receita) AS valor_receita, 
((SUM(r.valor_receita)/(SELECT 
                            SUM(x.valor_receita) 
                        FROM receitas x 
                        WHERE YEAR(x.data_vencimento) <= YEAR(r.data_vencimento) 
                        AND MONTH(x.data_vencimento) <= MONTH(r.data_vencimento) 
                        AND x.id_usuario = r.id_usuario))*100) AS total
FROM receitas r
WHERE r.recebido = 1 
AND YEAR(r.data_vencimento) <= '2017' 
AND MONTH(r.data_vencimento) <= '06' 
AND r.id_usuario = 1;
```

**Edit:**

Não sei se a sintaxe está correta, não tenho como testar, mas acredito que ficaria assim:
Utilizando outra comparação para Mês / Ano e retornando uma coluna de total.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(r.valor_receita) AS valor_receita, 
    ((SUM(r.valor_receita)/(SELECT 
                                SUM(x.valor_receita) 
                            FROM receitas x 
                            WHERE x.data_vencimento <= r.data_vencimento
                            AND x.id_usuario = r.id_usuario))*100) AS percentual,
    (SELECT 
        SUM(x.valor_receita) 
    FROM receitas x 
    WHERE x.data_vencimento <= r.data_vencimento
    AND x.id_usuario = r.id_usuario) as total
FROM receitas r
WHERE r.recebido = 1 
and Date_Format(r.data_vencimento,'Y-%c') <= STR_TO_DATE('2017-06', '%Y-%c') 
AND r.id_usuario = 1;
```

Comment: Boa!! Funcionou!! Mas me tira uma dúvida.. caso eu queira adicionar aí mais um que me retorne o valor total da receita, como poderia ser feito?

Comment: aí você tem que repetir o subselect, fora do calculo, para ele ser retornado como uma coluna. Você pode diminuir mais um pouco o código tirando essa comparação de ano e mês para uma comparação de data truncada

Comment: "Você pode diminuir mais um pouco o código tirando essa comparação de ano e mês para uma comparação de data truncada"
Não faço ideia de como fazer isto... Já foi complicado pensar nesta maneira... é que eu tô usando um input month, q me retorna '2017-06' por exemplo.

Comment: Editei adicionando outra query, faça um teste por favor

Comment: Valeu cara, você é 10!! Funcionou certinho aqui!

Comment: =] não se esqueça de marcar como resposta. Obrigado